# Changing color of cursor in code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I have changed my codeblocks' background to dark and cursor color also i am changing from Settings->Editor->margins and carets..

But the color of cursor is changing back to black after some time (mostly when '[' ']' got autocompleted), but this is not consistent that when it will go back to black..

Can someone please suggest that what setting i am missing, or is it a bug in codeblocks ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Have you checked their buglist to see if the issue is mentioned? **EDIT:**  I just had a quick google for "Code::Blocks caret color bug" and found that the first link mentions just this issue. If you're not using a new version of C::B, you may well find the issue to be resolved. Here: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18955.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't get their fix but i have disabled auto complete of braces and now it is working fine.

Comment: in my opinion the whole theme changing system of code::blocks is a mess

Comment: This behavior is back as of CB 20.03

Answer (score 6):

Having problem with color of cursor with black background see how to
change the color of cursor

> Settings->Editor->Margins and Caret

> after going to Margins and Caret their will be color option click.Now also  having doubts
> [[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiQC2.png]] copy and paste this is my pic then u will understand

Comment: I was having the same issue, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue and could not find any proper fix but figured out a hack. Instead of using line use block in the style and it will work fine. This way you do not have to disable autocompletion of braces as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't s bug as of now in codeblocks 17.12 which is the latest version at the time of writing this answer. For your problem, well you don't have to disable autocomplete instead go to settings>editor>syntax highlighting. Select the matching braces higlight option and select the color you want for fore ground and background.
[For installing themes refer this article.](https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/change-editor-theme-for-code-blocks-windows-linux-mac-92e9c15cbca4)

Answer (score 0):

for changing cursor color need: Go to setting => Editor => margin and caret => caret

part => color , so we can change cursor color of this part to your favorite color.